# LFS: What is the toolchain and why is it important?

Tags: linux, compiling, glibc

I'm going through Linux from Scratch and I'm on the [page](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter05/toolchaintechnotes.html) that discusses the toolchain. Up until this point I've understood everything, but I don't understand the term "toolchain".

From what I've read the toolchain is a set of tools that will be used to compile tools on the new distribution. This is required so that software isn't compiled with the host compiler.

Am I correct in thinking that the hosts tools (I believe it's the compiler that's being built at this stage) have to be used to compile Glibc, Binutils etc? And then once that is done the newly compiled compiler is used to build other tools to create the OS?

This part is very sketchy, and Googling around isn't yielding may useful results. If anyone has any useful resources to share that will help me understand this better that would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The toolchain is simply tools to build software (compiler, assembler, linker, libraries, and a few useful utilities).

In this case the important part is *host-independent* - that is independent of the tools downloaded.

There are several reasons why you might want to rebuild the tools:

- It is harder to sneak in backdoors (though not impossible)
- Compile parameters can be tweaked to fit *your* system and not just being a general binary.
- You get the newest version of the tools.

Comment: Good answer; I'd add that these params include target CPU-specific optimizations, though. They don't have to be generic packages that will be guaranteed to work on any amd64 system, for example, so it can make full use of your shiny new i7's extensions and improve build time and execution speed.

Answer (score 1):

LFS rebuilds the toolchain (i.e. the compiler, the linker, the assembler, and the libraries used by all of them) three times:

- The first time uses the toolchain of the host system to build a new toolchain (`gcc`, `ld`, `binutils`, `glibc`, etc)on the target system. These tools will be linked to shared libraries on the host system, which would not be present were you to boot into your target system at this time. So...
- The second time the toolchain is built against the libraries installed on the target machine. This means the toolchain will work if you boot into the target system, but there is still some possibility things may be linked against the host system, and regardless the toolchain was still compiled with optimizations targeted at the host system, not the target system. So...
- The third time is the charm, and this time the toolchain will be completely "sanitized" of any links or attachments to your host system, and optimized for your target system.

This is perhaps the single most important part of building an LFS system, and it's very important to pay close attention to the instructions. In all of the LFS systems I've built (four to-date), this has been the one section where I've run into problems. Sometimes those problems didn't show up until much later, which as you can imagine is very frustrating.